# count the number of word occurances

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
head(Bigram_freq) 
words          freq 
168943  of the 2213   
123107  in the 1890   
251052  to the 1059   
94473  for the  984  
171900  on the  958  
248733   to be  847
```

I need the freq of the first word of each bigram. Example for the bigram "of the", I need to know how many times the word "of" Occurs.

Comment: What have you tried? And how would you know how many "of" were in the original text that were not part of a bigram?

Comment: I assumed something like this will work but i'm not getting the correct counts.                                                                                                              for (i in nrow(Bigram_freq)){
  Bigram_freq$count = sum((filter(Bigram_freq, Wi_1 == Wi_1[i]))$freq)
}

Comment: What i'm really having trouble with is looping and calculating the count for each item in the table. I was able to add a column with the first word of each bigram. I get the correct count if I use the following command: sum((filter(Bigram_freq, Wi_1 == Wi_1[1]))$freq)                                                     I'm just not able to add a column with the correct counts for each row.